# How does changing IP and mask by ifconfig work?

Tags: networking, shell

I am sorry for this rudimentary question, but I cannot find a good answer.
Here is the effort to change IP and mask:

```
# ifconfig eth0
eth0: ip 192.168.0.133 mask 0.0.0.0 flags [up broadcast running multicast]
# ifconfig eth0 192.168.0.144 netmask 255.255.255.0
# ifconfig eth0
eth0: ip 192.168.0.144 mask 255.255.255.0 flags [up broadcast running multicast]
```

Everything appears to work based on the responses to the commands.  However, when I check the IP and mask on the Android device (Settings > WIRELESS & NETWORK > MORE... > Ethernet > Advanced Configuration), nothing changes.  After rebooting the device, "ifconfig eth0" returns the old values 192.168.0.133 and 0.0.0.0.

**DHCP is disabled**.

Could anyone shed some light on this?

Comment: "After rebooting the device" is the key here. To permanently apply changes, you'd have to integrate that into the boot process (change the default values which otherwise will override yours). Depending on the ROM this might require modifying the boot image – or just the `build.prop` (e.g. the value of `net.rmnet0.local-ip` if `rmnet0` is your WiFi). I'm not 100% sure as I've not tried it yet.

Comment: @Izzy The strange thing is that I can change those parameters via the UI of Android(i.e. Settings > WIRELESS & NETWORK > MORE... > Ethernet > Advanced Configuration), and the change will stay after rebooting.   I thought ifconfig would do exactly what the UI does.  I was wrong apparently.

Comment: I'd expect the UI to store changes in a config – so it's like what I wrote before: on the next boot, that config would be used. If it's for a specific WiFi, it should go to `/system/etc/wifi/wpa_supplicant.conf` in the details for that network AFAIK. Not sure for "default" settings not bound to a specific WiFi.

Comment: @Izzy It looks like that the changes are stored in directory /etc for Ethernet, but I cannot see the contents of the directory with File Explorer.  "chmod 777 /etc" failed.

Comment: `/etc` is a symlink to `/system/etc`, and `/system` is mounted read-only – so simply `chmod 0777 /etc` won't do anything here ;)

Comment: @Izzy Thank you for the tip.  I was looking at the directory because I read this post: http://superuser.com/questions/564797/change-ip-address-permanently-with-ifconfig-in-debian  I did not see any Ethernet settings in your mentioned file.

Comment: Of course not. Let me quote myself with emphasis set: *If it's **for a specific WiFi,** it should go to `/system/etc/wifi/wpa_supplicant.conf`* (WPA stands for [Wi-Fi Protected Access](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wi-Fi_Protected_Access), so this is for per-AP-config). Moreover I simply *expected* it to go there if it's for a specific WiFi. I've not verified it, sorry. I'm pretty sure it is stored somewhere from the UI (and that's the place the UI stores AP data); it might well be other IP settings go to some settings database.